# Cannot install "mathutils" in python

Tags: python, installation, pip, failed-installation

I tried everything. From pip and source code. However it keeps showing error.

```
            |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> mathutils

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I tired with anaconda, with just Python, either pip install or build source package. Nothing is working.